# Android Resume Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, resume

In my app, I start an activity and then on button click, display an http url (using Intent - VIEW_ACTION)

So when in the middle of the activity, if the user clicks the button called "Google", it opens up google.com in the browser.

When I hit the back button, it comes back to my original activity screen. How can I get my activity to resume from where it left of?

Thanks
George

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving Activity state in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look of this post:

[Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)